# Rational Numbers and Equivalence Classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Describe the rational numbers as the equivalence classes for an equivalence relation on certain pairs of integers.

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you would include what you have tried to do to solve the question, where you got stuck, and why. Also, questions usually have question marks.

Answer (score 4):

Two rationals $a/b$ and $c/d$ are the same if and only if $ad=bc$. This is a hint to consider the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ if and only if $ad=bc$. There is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of equivalence classes of pairs of integers under this relation and the rational numbers. The bijection is given by $\overline{(a,b)}\mapsto \frac{a}{b}$. You have to verify that this map is well defined and that it is in fact a bijection.

EDIT: You have to consider only pairs $(a,b)$ with $b\neq 0$ because if you do not have this restriction the relation is not transitive (for example $(1,1)\sim (0,0)$ and $(0,0)\sim (1,2)$ but $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are not related).

Comment: In the second sentence, did you mean $ad = bc$?

Comment: Yes! I edited the answer.